# ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) Error 403: <SERVICE ACCOUNT> does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, service-accounts, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-shell

I am trying to build a docker image from the Pub/Sub tutorial on Google (link [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/pubsub)). I am running this command: `gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/project_id/pubsub` but for some reason I get the error mentioned in the title: `ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) INVALID_ARGUMENT: could not resolve source: googleapi: Error 403: <SERVICE ACCOUNT> does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object., forbidden`. I gave the service account the `roles/storage.admin` role and that didn't work. I even went as far as made the service account an owner and I still got the same error.

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out. When using Cloud Build, GCP uses an entirely separate service account for this. It looks something like: `<random-id>@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com`. Add the **Cloud Build Service Account** role and the **Storage Admin** role to this service account fixed the problem.

Comment: The ID isn't random, it's the project number that the service account belongs to.

Comment: I tried your way but still got the error.